# How can I dynamically tie my form into Formik, in React functional component

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik

I'm building a React component which loads form data dynamically from an external API call. I'll need to submit it back to another API endpoint after the user completes it.

here it is:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { useFormik } from "formik";

const FORM = () => {

  const [form, setForm] = useState([]);
  const [submission, setSubmission] = useState({});

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: "",
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const formData = await axios.get("https://apicall.com/fakeendpoint");
      setForm(formData.data);
    })();  
  }, []);

  return (
    <form>
        {form.map((value, index) => {
          if (value.fieldType === "text") {
            return (
              <TextField 
                key={index} 
                id={value.name}
                label={value.label}
              />
            );
          } 
          if (value.fieldType === "select") {
            return (
              <TextField 
                select={true}
                key={index} 
                id={value.name}
                label={value.label}
              >
                {value.options.map((option) => (
                  <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                    {option.label}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </TextField>
            );
          }
        })}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
  );
};
 
export default FORM;
```

The API call is coming in ok (yeah i now i need some error handle on that) and I am able to populate the fields and get the form on the page. Where I am having trouble (and im newer to Formik so bear with me) is i need to do validation and submission. I do not really know how to handle the values, usually i'd write some type of static code for the variables, test them and then submit.

*usually* i'd set a field for "name" and one for "email" for example. In this case i can't write those fields in because they come from the API and we have no idea what they are until we get the call response.

My code handles the field creation but i need to wire for validation and submission and want to use Formik.

How can i accomplish a dynamic form (thru formik) which is wired for validation and submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I solved it with <Formik> component instead of useFormik() hook. not sure why useFormik fails on dynamic validation, but anyway, after switching to <Formik>, below is the code which worked for me. please check key points after the below code snippet as well.

```
<Formik
innerRef={formikRef}
initialValues={request || emptyRequest  //Mostafa: edit or new: if request state is avaialble then use it otherwise use emptyRequest.
}
enableReinitialize="true"
onSubmit={(values) => {
    saveRequest(values);
}}

validate={(data) => {
    let errors = {};

    if (!data.categoryId) {
        errors.categoryId = 'Request Category is required.';
    }

    //Mostafa: Dynamic validation => as the component is re-rendered, the validation is set again after request category is changed. React is interesting and a lot of repetitive work is done.
    if (requestCategoryFields)
        requestCategoryFields.map(rcField => {
            if (rcField.fieldMandatory) { //1- check Mandatory
                if (!data.dynamicAttrsMap[rcField.fieldPropertyName]) {
                    if (!errors.dynamicAttrsMap) //Mostafa: Need to initialize the object in errors, otherwise Formik will not work properly.
                        errors.dynamicAttrsMap = {}
                    errors.dynamicAttrsMap[rcField.fieldPropertyName] = rcField.fieldLabel + ' is required.';
                }
            }
            if (rcField.validationRegex) { //2- check Regex
                if (data.dynamicAttrsMap[rcField.fieldPropertyName]) {
                    var regex = new RegExp(rcField.validationRegex); //Using RegExp object for dynamic regex patterns.
                    if (!regex.test(data.dynamicAttrsMap[rcField.fieldPropertyName])) {
                        if (!errors.dynamicAttrsMap) //Mostafa: Need to initialize the object in errors, otherwise Formik will not work properly.
                            errors.dynamicAttrsMap = {}

                        if (errors.dynamicAttrsMap[rcField.fieldPropertyName]) //add an Line Feed if another errors line already exists, just for a readable multi-line message.
                            errors.dynamicAttrsMap[rcField.fieldPropertyName] += '\n';

                        errors.dynamicAttrsMap[rcField.fieldPropertyName] = rcField.validationFailedMessage; //Regex validaiton error and help is supposed to be already provided in Field defintion by admin user.
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    return errors;
}}>
{({errors,handleBlur,handleChange,handleSubmit,resetForm,setFieldValue,isSubmitting,isValid,dirty,touched,values
}) => (
    <form autoComplete="off" noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="card">
        <div className="grid p-fluid mt-2">

            <div className="field col-12 lg:col-6 md:col-6">
                <span className="p-float-label p-input-icon-right">
                    <Dropdown name="categoryId" id="categoryId" value={values.categoryId} onChange={e => { handleRequestCategoryChange(e, handleChange, setFieldValue) }}
                        filter showClear filterBy="name"
                        className={classNames({ 'p-invalid': isFormFieldValid(touched, errors, 'categoryId') })}
                        itemTemplate={requestCategoryItemTemplate} valueTemplate={selectedRequestCategoryValueTemplate}
                        options={requestCategories} optionLabel="name" optionValue="id" />
                    <label htmlFor="categoryId" className={classNames({ 'p-error': isFormFieldValid(touched, errors, 'categoryId') })}>Request Category*</label>
                </span>
                {getFormErrorMessage(touched, errors, 'siteId')}
            </div>

            {
                //Here goes the dynamic fields
                requestCategoryFields && requestCategoryFields.map(rcField => {
                    return (
                        <DynamicField field={rcField} values={values} touched={touched} errors={errors} handleBlur={handleBlur} 
                        handleChange={handleChange} isFormFieldValid={isFormFieldValid} getFormErrorMessage={getFormErrorMessage} 
                        crudService={qaCrudService} toast={toast} />
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
        <div className="p-dialog-footer">
            <Button type="button" label="Cancel" icon="pi pi-times" className="p-button p-component p-button-text"
                onClick={() => {
                    resetForm();
                    hideDialog();
                }} />
            <Button type="submit" label="Save" icon="pi pi-check" className="p-button p-component p-button-text" />
        </div>
    </form>
)}
```

Key points:

1. My dynamic fields also come from a remote API, by selecting the categoryId `DropDown`, and are set into the `requestCategoryFields` state.
2. I store the dynamic fields' values in a nested object called `dynamicAttrsMap` inside my main object which is called `request` as I have static fields as well.
3. I used `validate` props which includes one static validation for `categoryId` field, and then a loop (map) that adds dynamic validation for all other dynamic fields. **this strategy works as with every state change, your component is re-rendered and your validation is created from scratch.**
4. I have two kinds of validation, one checks the existence of value for mandatory fields. And the other checks a regex validation for the contents of the dynamic fields if needed.
5. I moved the rendering of dynamic fields to a separate component `<DynamicField>` for better modularization. please check [my DynamicField component](https://github.com/mostafamirzaee/sakai-react/blob/patch-2/src/components/DynamicField.js)
6. you can move the validation props to a `const` for better coding; here my code is a bit messy.
7. I used two `const`, for better coding, for error messages and CSS as below:

> ```
> const isFormFieldValid = (touched, errors, name) => { return Boolean(getIn(touched, name) && getIn(errors, name)) };
>
> const getFormErrorMessage = (touched, errors, name) => {
>     return isFormFieldValid(touched, errors, name) && <small className="p-error">{getIn(errors, name)}</small>;
> };
> ```

please check out my complete component at [my GitHub Here](https://github.com/mostafamirzaee/sakai-react/blob/patch-2/src/pages/qa/RequestCrud.js) for better understanding. and comment for any clarification if you need. because I know how tricky Formik can sometimes be. we have to help out each other.

Comment: yeah even tho many devs requirements might be to use the HOC withFormik, i've found the simpler Formik component to work much better in situations where with formik is not needed.

Answer (score -2):

Adding `enableReinitialize` to formik

```
useFormik({
    initialValues: initialData,
    enableReinitialize: true,
    onSubmit: values => {
      // Do something
    }
});
```

[FORMIK Doc](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean)

Comment: reinitialization is totally irrelevant to the question.